# Looking up a Python dictionary value where the key is a timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary containing keys which were stored as date and timestamps.  If I look up the keys with the following:

```
print(ActiveByInterval.keys())
```

This is my output:

```
dict_keys([Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00')])
```

However, if I try to fetch an item by one of these keys, I receive an error.  I have tried the following:

```
print(ActiveByInterval[Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00')])
error:  name 'Timestamp' is not defined

print(ActiveByInterval['Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00')'])
error:  invalid syntax

print(ActiveByInterval[('2017-07-01 00:00:00')])
error:  invalid syntax

print(ActiveByInterval['2017-07-01 00:00:00'])
error:  keyerror

print(ActiveByInterval[2017-07-01 00:00:00])
error:  invaluid token
```

How can I call a value by one of these keys?

Comment: Looks like "Timestamp" isn't defined in your script - have you imported/defined it?

Comment: Are these pandas timestamps? You might want to import it into your script, so you can construct your lookups correctly.

Comment: Correct - these were Pandas timestamps.  Here is how they were defined earlier in the script:  pd.to_datetime(timeframe, format='%m/%Y')

Comment: I am attempting to get filtered dataframes I will have to reuse through the script by the user defined time intervals.  Should I add these in as strings, or is there a better way?

Comment: `print(ActiveByInterval[Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00')])` looks correct but you need to import `Timestamp` definition from somewhere first

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for this guidance - this actually helped me solve.  I changed your syntax to print(ActiveByInterval[pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00')]) and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Use -

```
from pandas import Timestamp
```

Answer (score -2):

print(ActiveByInterval[pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00')]) worked.